# Catching Next, Prev ACtions

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I was wondering how I can reload the calendar when the next and previous buttons are click. Right now I have it loading the calendar with the correct data for one day, but it doesn't refresh when I click previous and next.

EDIT:

```
var Calendar = function () {
return {
    //main function to initiate the module
    init: function () {
        Calendar.initCalendar();
    },

    initCalendar: function () {

        if (!jQuery().fullCalendar) {
            return;
        }

        var eventID = 0;
        var eventsArr = new Array();            
        var date = new Date();
        var d = date.getDate();
        var dayOfWeek = date.getDay() + 1;
        var m = date.getMonth();
        var y = date.getFullYear();
        var currentDate = y + "-" + m + "-" + d;
        var h = {};

        if (App.isRTL()) {
             if ($('#calendar').parents(".portlet").width() <= 720) {
                $('#calendar').addClass("mobile");
                h = {
                    right: 'title, prev, next',
                    center: '',
                    right: 'agendaDay, agendaWeek, month, today'
                };
            } else {
                $('#calendar').removeClass("mobile");
                h = {
                    right: 'title',
                    center: '',
                    left: 'agendaDay, agendaWeek, month, today, prev,next'
                };
            }                
        } else {
             if ($('#calendar').parents(".portlet").width() <= 720) {
                $('#calendar').addClass("mobile");
                h = {
                    left: 'title, prev, next',
                    center: '',
                    right: 'today,month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                };
            } else {
                $('#calendar').removeClass("mobile");
                h = {
                    left: 'title',
                    center: '',
                    right: 'prev, next'
                };
            }
        }

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('destroy'); // destroy the calendar

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({ //re-initialize the calendar
            defaultView: 'agendaDay',
            header: h,
            slotMinutes: 5,
            editable: true,
            droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar !!!
            drop: function (date, allDay) { // this function is called when something is dropped

                // retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object
                var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');
                // we need to copy it, so that multiple events don't have a reference to the same object
                var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);

                // assign it the date that was reported
                copiedEventObject.start = date;
                copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;
                copiedEventObject.className = $(this).attr("data-class");

                // render the event on the calendar
                // the last `true` argument determines if the event "sticks" (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/)
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);

                // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
                if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
                    // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
                    $(this).remove();
                }
            },
            events: {
                url: 'api.php',
                cache: true,
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    day: dayOfWeek,
                    callback: "get_classes"
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
                },
            },
            eventClick: function(event, element) {
                $('#overlay').show();
                $('#popup').load('addmember.php', {
                    eventID : event.id,
                    currentDate : currentDate
                });
                $('#popup').show();
                disable_scroll();
            }
        });
    }  
};
```

Thats my create calendar code.

Comment: Can you show some code please. How are you adding the events?

Comment: just updated my question

Comment: Instead of using events try using eventSources [link]http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/eventSources/ callback.

Comment: i dont think that will work because there could be an infinite number of days and also a random date chosen. I need to refresh the calendar whenever the > or < buttons are pressed.

Answer (score 0):

So what you want is only to show events in a specific time range, lets say one Month, i mean the month you are visualizing in the moment. If thats the case when you fetch your events you will have to pass the time range you want to the server side, after that return the number of events, throught lets say JSON or XML whatever you want to the client side that will populate that time range.

for example:

```
 var yourinfinitesource = {
            infinitesourceone: {               
                url: api.php,
                type: 'POST',  
                data:{  
                    'year':y                            
                },
                cache: false,              
                color: '#6C92A8',
                textColor: 'white'                             
            }   
    };

 var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
 ...
 eventSources: [yourinfinitesource.infinitesourceone],
 ...
 });
```

Notice the Headers going to the server side:

[image]

Fullcalendar allways pass start: [unix time stamp] and end: [unix time stamp] , and this is allways the first and the last day you can visualize in the calendar.

So if you want to load only the events for that time range you can use this in your server side. Or like you can see in the year in the header is when i pass in data: { 'year':y } like this, you can use the same method to pass a diferent time range to load.

Try and use eventSources like this...for me they allways refresh everytime i click the prev,next button...

Have you tried this:

```
calendar.fullCalendar( 'refresh' );
```

If you need any further explanation let me know. good luck

Comment: That makes sense. I need to only show 1 day at a time though. If I pass the year, will it automatically show those events for everyday when I click the arrows?

Comment: If you load a whole year of events and if you show the day view, then yes...but if you want to load one day at a time you should use only day view and your time range ( passed to server ) should be something like this [2013-11-23 06:00:00 <-> 2013-11-23 23:00:00]...

Whats your point?